# Lubuntu battery monitor always says 100%

Tags: 11.10, battery, lubuntu

While using lubuntu-desktop I added the battery-monitor to the panel.  It seems to be essentially useless as the only information I get from it is whether the power cable is plugged in or not because even while discharging the battery monitor always stays stuck at 100%.  I've tried resetting the panel which doesn't fix the problem.  acpi gives the correct battery information.  Is there an alternate battery monitor or a work around for this?

My preference is to have something that works and displays the battery information on the panel.  I can check my battery status on the command line but that doesn't help if I just want a fast easy check.

I've tried conky but I can't get the ${battery} command or anything related to that to display the information even though calling acpi from the command line gives the correct battery status.  I could probably write something for conky to just parse and display the output of a call to acpi but I would much rather have a fix or alternative to the battery monitor in the panel.

Comment: ... and I was just going to post an answer based on conky!  great minds think alike...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lightweight battery monitor called batti that may work for you.

[Download](http://code.google.com/p/batti-gtk/downloads/detail?name=batti-0.3.8.tar.gz&can=2&q=) the compressed tar file.

Uncompress it: `tar -zxvf batti-0.3.8.tar.gz`

Test run the application:

```
cd batti-0.3.8
./batti
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it to autostart on log in but it works great!

Comment: Use my answer here to help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78926/openbox-doesnt-start-xcompmgr-at-start-up/80311#80311

Comment: Perfect.  I was messing around with the autostart file before but I couldn't get it to work.  I rebuilt and reinstalled it though and everything seems to work now.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have lubuntu and upgraded to 11.10 as well and my battery icon was having the exact same problem and I tried some solution programs (batti, vubat, etc) and wasn't satisfied, so I kept on looking and discovered Xfce Power Manager. I'm not sure how 'lightweight' it is or whether it was already supposed to be installed, but it appears to be very similar, if not the same, as the original gui I'd become used to. Try it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a battery monitor called IBAM (see [link](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ibam-the-intelligent-battery-monitor-for-laptops.html)). Simply install the 'ibam' package and run 'ibam' in the terminal. It may not sit next to your clock on your desktop, but you can check it at any time to see how your battery is doing.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still hoping for something that will sit in the panel as I can always just use acpi to figure out how the battery is doing.  But having a constant easy to check visual is what I'm really after here if possible.