# Where is the xcompmgr file located?

Tags: lubuntu, docky, xcompmgr

I'm on Lubuntu 11.10. I'd like to add **xcompmgr** as part of my autostart programs on logon (to use it in combination with Docky). I know all I have to do is to copy its icon into my /home/myname/.config/autostart. Problem is, I can't locate xcompmgr. I've looked in /usr/share/applications, to no avail. Where could I find it?

Comment: try `locate xcompmgr` from command line.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78926/openbox-doesnt-start-xcompmgr-at-start-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to find the location of executables - for example:

```
dad@dad-VirtualBox:~$ which xcompmgr
/usr/bin/xcompmgr
dad@dad-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/xcompmgr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30356 2010-05-13 07:06 /usr/bin/xcompmgr
```

If you want xcompmgr to start-up automatically you will not need to worry about including the exact & full path to the executable since it `/usr/bin` is a standard path location.  See my linked answer on how to add xcompmgr to the startup script for lubuntu

---

Linked Question:

1. [How to start applications such as xcompmgr at start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78926/openbox-doesnt-start-xcompmgr-at-start-up)

Comment: I followed your instructions, that is, created a xcompmgr desktop file. And it worked perfectly! Thanks.