# How to prevent my screen from either dimming or the screen-lock starting when watching YouTube?

Tags: power-management

My screen brightness used to dim after a few seconds to preserve battery. This is default in Ubuntu 12.04. However when watching video it should not dim.

This works correctly when I watch videos using native applications like VLC. With in-browser video, however, the screen is not prevented from dimming.
This is very annoying as you have to move your cursor every 10 seconds or so.

I used to use Mac OSX where I had the same dimming settings and Flash videos were taken into account correctly.

**Anyone an idea how you can make YouTube prevent your screen from dimming?**

Comment: So, since this is a problem that most Ubuntu users want a solution for, can we consider this a bug in the OS or a bug in the software (Flash, Chrome, Firefox) and get a fix so that every user doesn't need to come to this AskUbuntu page?

Comment: I appreciate all the help but this is ridiculous that it happens on 2016.
Come on, these are basic stuff that aren't supported. Also HTML5 Video - why is it so slow and buggy? Is it such a huge problem to fix..? It was supposed to replace Flash.. now it seems ridiculous.

Comment: Personally, I appreciate that my browser can't prevent my computer from locking, so I do **not** believe this is a bug.  What you're asking for could leave your computer in a less secure setup.

Comment: @earthmeLon or anyone, can you explain how will it be less safe?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**HOWTO: Disable screen saver while Flash is running**

Create a bash text file containing

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Cleanup any bad state we left behind if the user exited while flash was
# running
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type bool true

we_turned_it_off=0

while true; do
    sleep 60
    flash_on=0

    for pid in `pgrep firefox` ; do
        if grep libflashplayer /proc/$pid/maps > /dev/null ; then
            flash_on=1
        fi
        
        ss_on=`gconftool-2 -g /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled`

        if [ "$flash_on" = "1" ] && [ "$ss_on" = "true" ]; then
            gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled \
                --type bool false
            we_turned_it_off=1
        elif [ "$flash_on" = "0" ] && [ "$ss_on" = "false" ] \
                && [ "$we_turned_it_off" = "1" ]; then
            gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled \
                --type bool true
            we_turned_it_off=0
        fi

    done
done
```

Make the script executable by running:

```
chmod +x ~/path/to/script/flash_saver.sh
```

Run the script:

```
~/path/to/script/flash_saver.sh
```

If you prefer, you can set this script to run at logon by doing the following:

1. Run the program "Startup Applications"
2. Click "Add"
3. Under name type "FlashMonitor" or something you will recognise
4. Under command type the path to the script
5. Under comment (if you want) type a brief description.  E.g. "Stops screen turning off when Flash is running"

**Source: [HOWTO: Disable screen saver while Flash is running - ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090393)**

Comment: If I could I'd vote this up +5. The script from the ubuntu forum is incredibly well written as is your answer. Also big thumb up for actually including the source.

Comment: One can tell. At home I used a similar but much dirtier script which got lost in a recent reinstall. So I'm really grateful and once again convinced I should spend more time googling and less time writing scripts myself.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/196/

Comment: seems like the key is now `/org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/idle_activation_enabled`

Comment: If you are sure then edit that into the answer

Comment: @njallam This doesn't work with chromium. I replaced `pgrep firefox` with `pgrep chromium`. Still it doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to help there.  The forum post linked in the answer gave me all the information.  I think Caffeine would be the best solution as it is easier to use and I believe you can also set it to activate upon flash being used.

Comment: This indeed only works for Firefox. Anyone able to rewrite this for multiple-browser support?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and this does not seem to work for me. Anyone else out there who also have problems on Ubuntu 13.10? Or maybe it's just Gnome 3.8 that overruns this behavior somehow?

Comment: will it work with html5 video player?

Comment: HTML5 video support is needed indeed.

Comment: Did you maybe mean for the pid for loop to be just around the first if block?

Comment: I just discovered your answer, and noted that in my case the libflashplayer.so entries are found in the maps file of the process `plugin-container` and not in that of `firefox`. However, `pgrep plugin-container` does not give the PID of that process. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Why on earth don't desktop linux distributions put this on by default? these are the things that make me need to explain to friends why I still use Linux.

Answer (score 32):

#### EDIT

This probably will not work if you are using an Ubuntu version newer than 12.04 (have tried in 13.04 and 13.10 and it just does not work at all). It seems the main developer is not working anymore in this project, so the chances of it being fixed are not good.

---

In my system (Ubuntu 11.10) i use [Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecaffeine-developers/+archive/ppa). You can try if it works in Xubuntu too. It adds a notification area icon where you can enable/disable screensaver for some programs. To install Caffeine, do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

Then execute in a terminal:

```
caffeine -p &
```

You can then choose the programs that should disable the screensaver:
`vlc` for VLC, `mplayer` for Movie Player, etc.

[image: Caffeine Preferences]

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is running pretty fine on 12.04, Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for contributing a solution, but this is the best solution? Is this not a bug? It's got to be a bug. This happens on gnome, but not on unity.

Comment: I am now on 12.04 and I still use that application, not to stop the screensaver but to disable decrease of screen brightness quickly. For what I saw if it is a bug, it is in the browser: it should be his responsibility to inhibit the screensaver when in fullscreen.

Comment: Doesn't install in 13.10

Comment: @NoBugs It does not work in 13.04/10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1174400

Comment: This answer needs to be updated, since Caffeine even works in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. ;)

Answer (score 14):

There is a nice little script on [GitHub called lightsOn](https://github.com/iye/lightsOn) which should do the trick you want.

Basically it looks for full screen video (flash in firefox or chromium, mplayer or vlc) and if so disable xscreensaver and also the auto power-manager dim screen capability.

from the script itself:

```
HOW TO USE: Start the script with the number of seconds you want the checks
for fullscreen to be done. Example:
 "./lightsOn.sh 120 &" will Check every 120 seconds if Mplayer,
 VLC, Firefox or Chromium are fullscreen and delay screensaver and Power Management if so.
 You want the number of seconds to be ~10 seconds less than the time it takes
 your screensaver or Power Management to activate.
 If you don't pass an argument, the checks are done every 50 seconds.
```

Thus call the script from your autostart folder as [per my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78926/openbox-doesnt-start-xcompmgr-at-start-up/80311#80311).

Adjust the script for whether you are running flash/vlc/mplayer

remember to give the script execute rights to run i.e.

```
chmod +x lightsOn.sh
```

Comment: lightson seems unmaintained but there are alive forks (https://github.com/partizand/lightsOn, https://github.com/unhammer/lightsOn)

Answer (score 12):

Not entirely what you're after but this little script would register a mouse movement each time it was run. You could drop it into cron to run once every x-amount-of-time.
That would stop the screen from turning off, and a 1 1 movement of the mouse is barely noticeable if it runs when you're NOT watching a video

```
#!/bin/bash
#move the mouse
xte 'mousermove 1 1'
```

I totally got this idea from an xkcd comic by the way. http://xkcd.com/196/

Answer (score 7):

For a pre-rolled equivalent to the script supplied by @njallam, with a neat little Gnome UI element, try the Caffeine applet:

https://launchpad.net/caffeine
http://ubuntu-tweak.com/app/caffeine/

Comment: I had Caffeine installed but didn't see you had to activate it to let it work. Thanks!

Comment: Info from Caffeine developers: “Flash video support is gone, as it was too complicated to keep it working.” So you can forget Flash video checkbox in its settings. However, if you are using Firefox, add `plugin-container` to the list of programs and Caffeine will activate on Flash videos properly (deactivation will be delayed slightly, as plugin-container doesn't unload immediately when you close the tab with video, it takes several minutes).

Answer (score 6):

Webupd8 had an [article](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/2-ways-to-temporarily-disable.html) about Caffeine and Lightson.sh to disable the screen saver while Flash or HTML5 videos are playing. The Lightson script works for both Firefox and Chrome and can be set to include VLC.  I hope this will help.

In case the code provided by Webupd8 to install the script follows:

```
mkdir -p ~/scripts && cd ~/scripts

wget https://raw.github.com/hotice/lightsOn/master/lightsOn.sh

chmod +x lightsOn.sh
```

Comment: The method used in that script (`lightsOn.sh`) to detect if the browser utilizes HTML5 player is not really good. In fact, the method determines if Firefox or Chromium is in full-screen... In rest the article is good and your answer is most approached about what I asked.

Comment: I have been to doing a little more research found a script based of CPU or Network activity.  It located at [on the Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=83166) it might give you a little better control.  Enjoy watching YouTube.

Answer (score 5):

You should not only check the screensaver options, but also the power management options, especially the "Put display to sleep when inactive for ..." option.

Note that on laptops, there are two settings with that name: when the laptop is running on AC power and when it is running on battery.

Answer (score 2):

Use Caffeine : [ppa page](https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ppa).

How to install:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

How to run:

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, then type `caffeine`.
2. Click the "Caffeine" icon, then click "Disable Screensaver".

Comment: I don't intend to disable screensaver. Anyway, I tried caffeine, but doesn't work in any way. I don't think that is updated to the latest version of Gnome.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu caffeine disables the screensaver of your computer it has nothing to do with your web browser.

Comment: @Alvar It has if you wish... Anyway, didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using a screensaver other than gnome-screensaver (which is the default screensaver in Ubuntu starting with the 11.10 version) [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/108567/147044) may be helpful.

Personally, I didn't change out gnome-screensaver for something else and, I don't know for what reasons, Caffeine doesn't work for me in any way (maybe is outdated).

That being said, starting from others' bash scripts ([this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090393), [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/247924/147044) and [this](https://github.com/iye/lightsOn/blob/master/lightsOn.sh)), I managed to make a new script, `gnome_screensaver_off.sh` that works perfectly for what I intended when YouTube is using Flash player for rendering videos.

### Disable gnome-screensaver while YouTube is using Flash player

Open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run next commands followed by instructions:

- `mkdir -p bin` - this command will make a `bin` directory in your `home` folder if you don't already have it.
- `gedit ~/bin/gnome_screensaver_off.sh` -this will create the new file `gnome_screensaver_off.sh` in gedit.
- Copy and paste there next script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Getting the previous configuration
back=$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac)

screensaver_is_off=0
delay=$[$back - 10]

# Defining the restore function
function restore {
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac $back
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery $back
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay $back

    bmin=$[$back / 60]
    #notify-send "Screen sleep time restored to $bmin minutes."

    notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "Screen sleep time restored to $bmin minutes."
}

# Defining the disable_screensaver function
function disable_screensaver {
    # Making sure the user don't mess up...
    trap 'restore && exit 0' INT HUP

    # Disabling sleep time
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac 0
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery 0
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0

    notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "Screen sleep time turned off."
}

while true; do
    if [ "$delay" -le "50" ]; then
        sleep 50
    else
        sleep $delay
    fi
    flash_on=0

    #Check if Chrome, Chromium or Firefox is open with a flash video running on it
    if pgrep -lfc ".*((c|C)hrome|chromium|firefox|).*flashp.*" > /dev/null ; then
            flash_on=1
    else
        flash_on=0  
    fi

    if [ "$flash_on" -eq "1" ] && [ "$back" -ne  "0" ] && [ "$screensaver_is_off" -eq "0" ]; then
        disable_screensaver
        screensaver_is_off=1
    elif [ "$flash_on" -eq "0" ] && [ "$screensaver_is_off" -eq "1" ]; then
        restore
        screensaver_is_off=0
    fi
done

exit 0
```

- Save the file and close it.
- Go back into terminal and run: `chmod +x gnome_screensaver_off.sh` - to grant execute access for the script.
- To run your new script, run `~/bin/gnome_screensaver_off.sh`.

If you prefer, you can set this script to run at logon by doing the following:

1. Search in **Dash** for **Startup Applications**, open it and click **Add**.
2. Under name type "YouTube Monitor" or something you will recognise.
3. Under command type "/home/$USER/bin/gnome_screensaver_off.sh" (change $USER with your username).
4. Under comment (if you want), type a brief description (e.g. "Stops screen turning off when Flash player is running in browser").

### Disable gnome-screensaver while YouTube is using [HTML5](http://www.youtube.com/html5) player

*The question remains open in this sense...*

<sup>Thanks for the suggestions offered by: [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom), [Meer Borg](https://askubuntu.com/users/75967/meer-borg), [njallam](https://askubuntu.com/a/171164/147044), [desgua](https://askubuntu.com/a/247924/147044) and others.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A little old, but here it is with multiple browsers support:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

# List your browsers here
browsers_list=( "firefox" "chrome" "chromium" "opera" )

# Cleanup any bad state we left behind if the user exited while flash was running
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type bool true

idle_off=0

while true; do

    sleep 60

    for browser in "${browsers_list[@]}" ; do
    for pid in `pgrep $browser` ; do

        flash_on=0
        if [ -O /proc/$pid/maps ] && grep libflashplayer /proc/$pid/maps > /dev/null ; then
            flash_on=1
        fi

        ss_on=`gconftool-2 -g /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled`

        if [ "$flash_on" = "1" ] && [ "$ss_on" = "true" ]; then
            gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type bool false
            idle_off=1
        elif [ "$flash_on" = "0" ] && [ "$ss_on" = "false" ] && [ "$idle_off" = "1" ]; then
            gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type bool true
            idle_off=0
        fi

    done
    done

done
```

Just save the script somewhere, `chmod +x` it, and add it to the StartupApplications.
There might be a way to list all available browsers using something like:

```
update-alternatives --list x-www-browser
```

But I don't know how to handle the fact that some executables don't have the name than their processes (for instance `/usr/bin/google-chrome` runs as `chrome`).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for HTML5 playback in Chrome**

*Overview*

The following script disables the screensaver if it finds an active full-screen Chrome session. By default it will run a check every 5 minutes. The script will automatically resume the screensaver if either of the following three conditions are met:

- window is not full-screen
- window is not in focus
- window does not exist anymore

*Script*

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Variables ##

ChromeWmClass="Google-chrome"
FullScreenProperty="_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN"
CheckInterval="300" # check every 5 minutes

## Main ##

while true; do

  sleep "$CheckInterval"

  ActiveWinID=$(xdotool getactivewindow)

  if [[ -z "$ActiveWinID" ]]; then
    continue
  fi

  ActiveWinProp=$(xprop -id "$ActiveWinID")

  if echo "$ActiveWinProp" | grep "$FullScreenProperty" > /dev/null 2>&1 \
  && echo "$ActiveWinProp" | grep "WM_CLASS" | grep "$ChromeWmClass" > /dev/null 2>&1
    then
      if [[ -z "$SuspendingID" ]]; then
        echo "Suspending screensaver for $ActiveWinID"
        xdg-screensaver suspend "$ActiveWinID"
        SuspendingID="$ActiveWinID"
      elif [[ "$ActiveWinID" = "$SuspendingID" ]]; then
        echo "$ActiveWinID is already suspending  screensaver."
      elif [[ -n "$SuspendingID" ]]; then
        echo "Resuming screensaver for $SuspendingID"
        xdg-screensaver resume "$SuspendingID"
        echo "Suspending screensaver for $ActiveWinID"
        xdg-screensaver suspend "$ActiveWinID"
        SuspendingID="$ActiveWinID"
      fi
    else
      if [[ -n "$SuspendingID" ]] \
      && xprop -id "$SuspendingID" > /dev/null 2>&1
        then
          echo "Resuming screensaver for $SuspendingID"
          xdg-screensaver resume "$SuspendingID"
          SuspendingID=""
        else
          echo "No change."
      fi
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest nonintellectual approach which is desktop-agnostic and relies on [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) would be to simulate a key stroke every N seconds.

I use a script called `heartbeat.sh`:

```shell
#!/bin/bash
while : 
do
    nice -n 1 xdotool key shift
    date +%T ## show some sign of life
    sleep 100
done
```

I launch the script while I play the video, and then stop it when it is not needed anymore.

`xdotool` can be installed with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`.

If you also want to have some kind of automatic audio detection, **and** you are ok with a PulseAudio-specific recipe, then below is a variation of the solution above that checks if audio is playing:

```shell
#!/bin/bash

while : 
do
    if [[ ! -z $(pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep RUNNING) ]] ; then
        echo 'Audio is playing. Inhibiting screensaver'
        nice -n 1 xdotool key shift ;
    else
        echo 'No audio detected'
    fi
    date +%T ## show some sign of life
    sleep 100
done
```

If using Alsa then the test would probably be something like (untested):

```shell
if [[ ! -z $(grep RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/pcm*/sub*/status) ]] ; then...
```

A potential downside of this solution is that your screen will not sleep even if you are just listening to music or radio, but I assume that in most cases this is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The VLC in [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/vlc?field.series_filter=lucid) in addition to being a current version of VLC also correctly implements screen saver inhibition.

You can add this PPA using this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/vlc
```

Comment: Many different questions appear to have been merged into this one. Check the edit history, and you may see that some of the questions included issues with the screen saver.

Answer (score 1):

**For those that like full or manual control at their hands**

This command line can set the screensaver delay time:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac 0
```

Use "0" (zero) to keep it on or another value to define the delay in seconds.

The following script will keep the screen on until some key is pressed.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# 
# To turn screen sleep time off for a while then back on
#
# by desgua 2013/01/27
#

# Getting the previous configuration
back=$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac)

# Defining the restore function
function RESTORE {

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac $back
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery $back
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay $back

bmin=$(echo "$back / 60" | bc)
#notify-send "Screen sleep time restored to $bmin minutes."
echo
echo "Screen sleep time restored to $bmin minutes."
echo 

exit 0
}

# Making sure the user don't mess up...
trap 'RESTORE && exit 0' INT HUP

# Disabling sleep time
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery 0
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0

echo
echo "Screen sleep time turned off."
echo 

#notify-send "Screen sleep time turned off."

# Waiting for user to press some key and then restore the previous configuration
read -n 1 -p 'Press any key to turn it on again. ' b

RESTORE

exit 0
```

How to run a script:

1. Copy the text into an empty file,
2. Save the file,
3. Make the file executable,
4. Run it from a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on what version of Ubuntu you are using.  In 11.10, you can find "System Settings" in by clicking the gear icon in the top right corner of the screen.  Select this, and in the dialog that pops up, select "Screen".  You can set the amount of time that your computer will be idle before the screen blanks with the dropdown menu, or disable that feature by clicking the button labeled "Lock".

If you have an older system, you may have to look elsewhere for this setting, but it is there somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, but I do not want to disable it permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply execute/set this command while startup :

```
gconftool --type string --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/fade/screen0/dim_unresponsive false
```

Also can you try unchecking the ***hardware acceleration*** option on firefox?

Comment: I said this before: *I don't intend to disable screensaver*. I want only to prevent my screen from dimming when watching YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

The script at the above top does not work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Unity. Here its updated variant which works:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

id_saved=0
sac_saved=0
sbat_saved=0
dim_saved=false

ss_save()
{
    id_saved=`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay`
    sac_saved=`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout`
    sbat_saved=`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout`
    dim_saved=`gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim`
}

ss_set()
{
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay "$1"
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout "$2"
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout "$3"
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim "$4"
}

ss_on()
{
    ss_set "$id_saved" "$sac_saved" "$sbat_saved" "$dim_saved"
}

ss_off()
{
    ss_set 0 0 0 false
}

trap ss_on EXIT

already_off=0
flash_on=0
ss_save

while true; do
    if top -bcw 200 | sed -e '1,/PID/d' | head -1 | grep flash > /dev/null
    then
        flash_on=1
        off_count=0
    else
        off_count=`expr $off_count + 1`
        echo "flash_off_count=$off_count"
        if [ $off_count -gt 5 ]; then
            flash_on=0
        fi
    fi

    if [ "$flash_on" = "1" -a "$already_off" = "0" ]; then
        echo "screensaver: off"
        ss_off
        already_off=1
    elif [ "$flash_on" = "0" -a "$already_off" = "1" ]; then
        echo "screensaver: on"
        ss_on
        already_off=0
    elif [ "$already_off" = "0" ]; then
        echo "screensaver: save possibly new params"
        ss_save # user may update the values
    fi

    sleep 30
done
```

BTW, this script disables screensaver ONLY when the video is playing, i.e. when flashplayer is in the top of CPU consumers.

Answer (score 0):

For those using **Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04** there is a simple yet useful Extension called Caffeine which provides a toggle icon which allows you to disable the light dimming and screen saver behaviour from the top bar with a click.

The extension can be installed following this link to the Gnome-Shell Extensions website:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/

Source: comments' section in this article:

http://www.maketecheasier.com/prevent-ubuntu-sleep-while-watching-video/

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

https://github.com/yanyingwang/shanghai-tools/blob/master/kit/the-bund-light.md

https://github.com/yanyingwang/shanghai-tools/blob/master/kit/the-bund-light.sh

Just download the `the-bund-light.sh` and add it to startbooting application:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool

cd ~ && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yanyingwang/shanghai-tools/master/kit/the-bund-light.sh

cat >> ~/.config/autostart/the-bund-light.sh.desktop <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=$HOME/shanghai-tools/kit/the-bund-light.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[zh_CN]=TheBundLight
Name=TheBundLight
Comment[zh_CN]=
Comment=
EOF
```

CAUTION:  the `Exec`'s value in the code should be path of `the-bund-light.sh` in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script as a workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
   xdotool key Shift_L
   sleep 1m
done
```

It simulates a left shift key press once every minute, which prevents the screen from going dim. The drawback of this, of course, is that you have to run the script every time you watch youtube. On the other hand, it is simple and works with most, if not all, configurations.

You may need to install this

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```