# xdotool mousemove blank screen script question

Tags: scripts

I have infamous screen going black after 10 minutes or so despite trying several solutions  to avoid it in Ubuntu 12.04

So i decided for the last solution which is emulating mouse move every 9 minutes
I've downloaded `xdotool`.

My questions, and i guess they require simple answers (which are needed, because I’m not really a comp freak):

1. Do I have to make a script for that.
2. How do I make a script and where do I save it.
3. How to make it running automatically (every time computer starts), if that's not happening by default

So, I want to just emulate a mouse move by one pixel every 9 minutes, so that it is not disturbing and is efficient in keeping screen not going black

After googling, I tried something like this :

Creating file `.noblackscreen.sh` in home directory (where documents, music... folders are);
typing in:

```
#!/bin/bash

while sleep 540
do

xdotool mousemove_relative 1 1

done
```

what do i do wrong
thanx so much

Comment: Duplicate of [How to prevent my screen from either dimming or the screen-lock starting when watching YouTube?](http://askubuntu.com/q/171143/25656)?

Answer (score 0):

The script does move the mouse pointer a little, every 540 seconds.

Have actually run it, either manually every time or automatically at startup? If not, open startup applications and add an entry with the command `sh ~/.noblackscreen.sh`. The script should now autostart at login.

If the script is already running, I'm out of ideas. Just a wild guess, but possibly the mouse got stuck in the lower right corner and the script has no effect? Or may be jiggling the mouse pointer has no effect?