# My screen turns off when I watch movies on YouTube

Tags: 13.04, screen, youtube, gnome-screensaver

When I use VLC or other media player, I can watch the movie until the end without touching the PC. If I watch a movie on YouTube using Chromium or Firefox my screen will turn off as is set in *System Settings* > *Brightness and Lock*. How to prevent this without to change the settings in *Brightness and Lock*.

**Edit:**

- My Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome 3.6.3.1 uses gnome-screensaver (I didn't installed any other screensaver).
- Any of the answers from this question didn't worked for me in 13.04: [How to prevent my screen from dimming when watching YouTube?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171143/how-to-prevent-my-screen-from-dimming-when-watching-youtube) - this question is related in 12.04.