# screensaver activates, screen fades, and computer goes to standby when watching video

Tags: video, screensaver

When watching a video in a web browser Ubuntu starts to fade out the screen and eventually goes to black after 2 minutes. I expect this because this is how I have my power settings set up. When I watch a movie in the video player the screen does not fade out. So it seems the system doesn't realize there is something running when a video is playing in the browser. Is there a way to fix this without making the power settings to always on? Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: possible duplicate of: [My screen turns off when I watch movies on YouTube](http://askubuntu.com/questions/301069/my-screen-turns-off-when-i-watch-movies-on-youtube)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Caffeine: "A status bar application able to temporarily prevent the activation of both the screensaver and the "sleep" powersaving mode."

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

Once it's installed, run Caffeine through the dash. You'll notice a small coffee cup icon (indicator) appear in the bar at the top of your screen. Click on that cup and activate, and check that "Start Caffeine on login" and "Enable for Flash Video" are both checked in the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

This page here shows you how to disable screen dimming when flash is in use and as most video players online are flash....:

[HOWTO: Disable screen saver while Flash is running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171143/how-to-prevent-my-screen-from-dimming-when-watching-youtube)

Comment: Those answers doesn't work in 13.04.

Comment: some of those answers DO work. In particular Caffeine. I'll post as an answer.