# How to disable screen lock timeout from a script?

Tags: scripts, lock-screen

I'm looking for a way to disable screen dimming and desktop locking timeout from a bash script on Ubuntu 13.10. The script should be run when user logs in (configured in Startup Applications window) or as a service before *lightdm* (from init.d).

I have found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/171164/129094) and tried the command:

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-screensaver/idle_activation_enabled --type bool false
```

It has actually changed that setting (I've checked with `gconftool-2 -g` and `gconf-editor`), but it doesn't seem to work like expected. Settings window still states that screen will turn off, and in fact, after 5 minutes screen turns off and I'm prompted to enter my password when I wake it up.

I've also tried looking around in `gconf-editor`, but I haven't found any settings that looked relevant.

So, how can I disable desktop locking and screen off timeout from a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer (I didn't try to change configuration)

I think that new Ubuntu(s) use `dconf` and not `gconf` --- try to look for parameters in `dconf-editor` (settable via command line with the confusing-named `gsettings`).

I think that the relevant schemas are around `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver`, at least for gnome. I do not have Unity installed so I think you need to research a bit around to adapt...

Comment: You were right, `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.idle-activation-enabled` and `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.lock-enabled` were the settings I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I've confirmed to work based on @Rmano's answer:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/idle-activation-enabled false
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled false
```

After executing any of those you should see settings changing immediately in `dconf-editor`, Settings center will reflect changes too. Finally, settings will be immediately applied, so you can wait given period of time and see that the screen saver won't turn on.