# Screen freezes after screen saver when watching fullscreen videos. Disable screensaver when using flash

Tags: firefox, flash, libraries, screensaver, proc

Update: `libflashplayer` is installed on my system, firefox just isnt using it.... I discovered this hack-sawing through my root directory with `ls -R / | grep libflashplayer`

---

I want to disable the screensaver when watching videos online because when it activates and I move the mouse to escape it, my video is frozen fullscreen. Everything is still running, the screen just wont update and I have to use the sysReq key to force a shutdown.

Im not sure about the underlying problem (maybe I should file a bug report?) but I just want to prevent the screensaver as a quick fix.

I found this old topic
[How to prevent my screen from either dimming or the screen-lock starting when watching YouTube?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171143/how-to-prevent-my-screen-from-either-dimming-or-the-screen-lock-starting-when-wa)
and wanted to comment my question there, but alas I do not have the reputation.

Im using Ubuntu14.04 x64 with the `flashplugin-installer`.

I would like to use the script provided in that thread (its very simple and elegant) but it seems `libflashplayer` is not what is being used by my system. In fact not a single library with flash in the name is being used, hence `grep flash /proc/$pid/maps` returns nothing.

Any suggestions on what library firefox might be using to render flash content?

And please don't suggest using caffeine, it no longer supports flash and was terribly buggy anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different version of flash, it may fix your problem.

Here's a script that installs the latest version of pepper flash on firefox. It might fix your problem.  https://db.tt/rHEJ2e0l

to run it, open terminal, cd into the location where the script is and install type:

```
chmod +x freshplayer_maintainer.sh; ./freshplayer_maintainer.sh
```

and the rest should be self explanatory